# WebSphere application server Traditional not starting

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am trying to start my websphere traditional application server from rational application developer. At the first time server started properly but after stopping it and starting it again next day it is giving admin exception: null pointer exception in the console

```
[12/7/22 14:47:15:934 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.deactivateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:1168)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.batch.endpointsensor.BatchSensorComponent.destroy(BatchSensorComponent.java:100)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.destroyComponent(ContainerHelper.java:341)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.destroyComponents(ContainerHelper.java:325)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.destroyComponents(ContainerImpl.java:607)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.destroy(ContainerImpl.java:598)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.destroy(ServerImpl.java:501)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:935 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:334)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:238)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:711)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:936 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:937 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:938 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:938 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:938 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:938 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:939 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:939 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:939 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:423)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:939 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:180)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:939 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[12/7/22 14:47:15:939 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.deactivateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:1141)
[12/7/22 14:47:15:940 IST] 00000001 SystemErr     R     ... 36 more
```

i am totally new to this can anyone explain me what can be issue as it worked before perfectly.

Comment: Try to start it manually from WAS profile directory and see if it starts correctly.

Comment: If the server is installed as developer mode, try reinstalling it as defualt

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what seemed to be the issue was that I had changed my JAVA_HOME and EXE4J_JAVA_HOME environment variables. Once I put them back to their previous values AND restarted my pc, I happily saw again the message *Server server1 open for e-business*